# Is it possible for the exponent of the denominator to be multiplied to the base? (Not Logarithmic)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I've been stuck with this question for a hours. The first equation is supposed to transform into the second equation, but I've never encountered a rule where **the exponent can be placed as a multiplier of the base**. I am not dealing with derivatives, and it's supposed to be simple algebra. I've attached a picture since I have no idea how to input in LaTex. Thank you so much.

The one with the red arrow is the first expression, the orange arrow is the second expression.
[How is that possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U252D.jpg)

More specifically, I am concerned how this is possible:
[How is dis possible??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKGDj.jpg)

Again, I apologize for not inputting it in LaTex. I really don't know how.

Comment: It's incorrectly written. They're not equal, it's just the first order Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: By the way: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much!